# How to create XFA enabled editable PDF using iText

Tags: itext

We have a requirement of creating editable PDF(not by using Adobe Live cycle or Acrobat), we have created Acroform(editable PDF) and try to save filled form. but Save option is disabled in Adobe Reader. Is there any way to enable save option in acroform without using Acrobat/Adobe LC? If it is not possible can we create XFAs without using Adobe LC? and lastly can we save/post the xml data of acroform in a local machine using Javascript or any other way?

Comment: The question is either unanswerable, or an attempt to do something that is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

You say *'Save option is disabled'* and that's completely normal.

It would be illegal for a third party (a company that is not Adobe) to create documents that are enabled in Adobe Reader, because Reader enabling involves encryption using a private key owned by Adobe. See http://support.itextpdf.com/node/24